# How to remove /public/nova/ from url?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5, laravel-nova

I have installed laravel and nova. For now url is `www.example.com/public/nova/login`. I need to remove `/public/nova/`. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Hey which page you are trying to access? To access nova admin the default url will be `www.example.com/nova`

Comment: Which server environment are you using?

Comment: I am trying to access nova login page with this url www.example.com.

Comment: I am using plesk server

Comment: is it possible?

Comment: And also I changed "repositories": [ { "type": "path",url": "./nova" }] to repositories": [ { "type": "path",url": "/" }] on composer.json. But not worked.

Comment: You have to point the url to `/htdocs/public`, by default it is `/htdocs`

Answer (score 2):

By default you can access the nova installation from

```
http://base_url/nova
```

If you want to change it, you can change the path from `app/config/nova.php` and update the path. eg.

```
'path' => '/admin',
```